# DiscoveryClient_USER-AUTH/user-auth-66b764457c-k628h:USER-AUTH:5071 - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, netflix-eureka

I'm currently working on my microservices project with java spring boot.
I dockerized everything correctly, but as soon as I try to implement everything on **Kubernetes** it starts to give me problems.

I run the command `kubectl logs mypodname` to look at the error and it prints me the following:

```
 2022-06-03 18:36:38.082  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
 2022-06-03 18:36:38.103  INFO 1 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/}, exception=I/O error on PUT request for "http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/USER-AUTH/user-auth-66b764457c-k628h:USER-AUTH:5071": Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused stacktrace=org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on PUT request for "http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/USER-AUTH/user-auth-66b764457c-k628h:USER-AUTH:5071": Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.sendHeartBeat(RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.java:99)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:121)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:80)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.renew(DiscoveryClient.java:893)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1457)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
   Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:87)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:776)
    ... 20 more
  Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:493)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:482)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:585)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    ... 33 more

 2022-06-03 18:36:38.103  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/}, exception=I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/": Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused stacktrace=org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/": Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.java:145)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.getApplications(RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.java:135)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:121)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:80)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1101)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1014)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1531)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1498)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
  Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:87)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:776)
    ... 23 more
 Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:493)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:482)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:585)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    ... 36 more
```

I've tried to change the yml regarding this microservice, but nothing happens.

**application-properties.yml**

```
 spring:
   servlet:
   multipart:
     max-file-size: 10MB
     max-request-size: 10MB
   application:
     name: USER-AUTH
   datasource:
     username: 'littleshops'
     password: 'littleshops'
     url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
        naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  mvc:
    throw-exception-if-no-handler-found: true
  web:
    resources:
      add-mappings: false

  server:
    port: 5071
    error:
      whitelabel:
        enabled: false

eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
    hostname: localhost
client:
   register-with-eureka: true
   fetch-registry: true
   service-url:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
 ---

 spring:
   datasource:
     username: ${spring_datasource_username}
     password: ${spring_datasource_password}
     url: ${spring_datasource_url}


 jwt:
   secret: 'mysecret'
```

**kubernetes.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: spring-config
data:
  dev-config.json:
  '{
    "spring.datasource.url": "jdbc:mysql://db-user:3308/users?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC",
   "spring.datasource.username": "myusername",
   "spring.datasource.password": "mypassword"
  }'
 ---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: user-auth
  labels:
    app: user-auth
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
   metadata:
    name: user-auth
    labels:
      app: user-auth
   spec:
      containers:
        - env:
          - name: SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                key: dev-config.json
                name: spring-config
          name: user-auth
          image: hassanmarji96/user-auth
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
           - containerPort: 5071
          resources:
               {}
      restartPolicy: Always
   selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: user-auth

   ---
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: user-auth-svc
  spec:
   selector:
       app: user-auth
     type: ClusterIP
     ports:
       - port: 80
         targetPort: 5071
```

Even if Eureka doesn't recognize the microservice, the microservice itself works..
I've tried even to add a / at the end of the defaultZone attribute but nothing.

This is the link to my repo: https://github.com/hassanmarji96/Backend_Littleshops